# Delays over AZURE BLOB STORAGE when log backup up of database to URL

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-blob-storage

I used Microsoft Azure Blob Storage for database log backup. The type of used Storage accounts is Geographically Redundant Storage (GRS) Account. I have the problem with speed of restore verify process, I mean, there are delays during verify restore.

We take a standard and mirrored backup to two different storage accounts, but there are difference of  restore verify time between these two storage accounts.
One of them takes time about two times more than another.

I want to note that we took log backup to disk every 10 minutes, but when we use this strategy over URL then log backup sequence is broken, so during 10 minutes backup and restore verify processes is not completed.

What do you recommend for best practice?
What can be the cause?
Is the URL speed slower compared to the disc?
What are the results of your experiences?

Example result of backup process over one database:

```
Date and time: 2018-07-04 12:26:46
Command: BACKUP LOG [TESTDB] TO URL = N'https://SAxxx02.blob.core.windows.net/containername/TESTDBWINCLUSTER$AOAG_TEST_1/TESTDB/LOG/TESTDBWINCLUSTER$AOAG_TEST_1_TESTDB_LOG_122646.trn' MIRROR TO URL = N'https://SAxxx01.blob.core.windows.net/containername/TESTDBWINCLUSTER$AOAG_TEST_1/TESTDB/LOG/TESTDBWINCLUSTER$AOAG_TEST_1_TESTDB_LOG_122646.trn' WITH CHECKSUM, COMPRESSION, FORMAT, DESCRIPTION = N'https://SAxxx01.blob.core.windows.net/containername;https://SAxxx02.blob.core.windows.net/containername'
Processed 58281 pages for database 'TESTDB', file 'TESTDB_log' on file 1.
BACKUP LOG successfully processed 58281 pages in 5.709 seconds (79.754 MB/sec).
Outcome: Succeeded
Duration: 00:00:09
Date and time: 2018-07-04 12:26:55

Date and time: 2018-07-04 12:26:55
Command: RESTORE VERIFYONLY FROM URL = N'https://SAxxx02.blob.core.windows.net/containername/TESTDBWINCLUSTER$AOAG_TEST_1/TESTDB/LOG/TESTDBWINCLUSTER$AOAG_TEST_1_TESTDB_LOG_122646.trn' WITH CHECKSUM
The backup set on file 1 is valid.
Outcome: Succeeded
Duration: 00:00:15
Date and time: 2018-07-04 12:27:10

Date and time: 2018-07-04 12:27:10
Command: RESTORE VERIFYONLY FROM URL = N'https://SAxxx01.blob.core.windows.net/containername/TESTDBWINCLUSTER$AOAG_TEST_1/TESTDB/LOG/TESTDBWINCLUSTER$AOAG_TEST_1_TESTDB_LOG_122646.trn' WITH CHECKSUM
The backup set on file 1 is valid.
Outcome: Succeeded
Duration: 00:00:27
Date and time: 2018-07-04 12:27:37
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You said you have two storage accounts – is one local LRS and one GRS .  The Geo Redundant storage would be twice as long on write in theory, but on read you would not expect it to be twice as slow.  So could you clarify the following detail also: Is your database in azure in the same region as one of your storage accounts?   Is the GRS storage “Primary" part Far away in another region – so all writes take twice as long.  I think they want the GRS "Primary" to be active in the local region with the secondary part of the GRS in another region you don’t know about.

Comment: Currently, both types of storage accounts are GRS. Both accounts have the same settings
Database servers, virtual maschines, VHD(SA) -all of theese are located West Europe.
The results of our tests are as follows:

Comment: 1. Primary Backup - SA01 -LRS (West Europe) 10 minute
 Mirror Backup -SA02- GRS (Primary - West Europe, North Europe) 05 minute

Comment: 2. Primary Backup- SA01-GRS (Primary - West Europe, North Europe) 10 minute
 Mirror Backup-SA02-GRS (Primary - West Europe, North Europe) 05 minute

Comment: 3. Mirror Backup-SA01-GRS (Primary - West Europe, North Europe) 10 minute
 Primary Backup-SA02-GRS (Primary - West Europe, North Europe) 05 minute   (Time is approximate)